# React table - Add a popover when column cell is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to add a hyperlink to the cell data Summary which when clicked can open a popover in one of the column.

```
 const columns = [
     {
         title: 'Name',
         data: 'name',
         searchable: true
     },
     {
         title: 'Summary',
         data: 'instanceName',
         searchable: true,
         render: (data, type, row) => `
            <div>
              <p style="color: green">Applied- ${this.calculatecount(row.name)}</p>
           </div>
                  `
 ];
```

How to make this Applied - (count) an hyperlink and when clicked should show a popover.
the number of the instances can be large so need to show the list in the popover.

```
  <Popover title="Successfully Applied">
             <div>
                 <p style="color: green">Names of the instances applied</p>
             </div>
      </Popover>
```